# .htaccess | Setting ErrorDocuments

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a `.htaccess` file, and I wanted to set up ErrorDocuments for most 4xx and 500 HTTP/1.1 errors (most won't be used, but better off prepared).

However, when the file has the following, it throws a `500 Internal Server Error` (I tried commenting this and it worked):

```
ErrorDocument 400 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 402 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 405 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 406 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 407 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 408 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 409 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 410 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 411 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 412 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 413 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 414 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 415 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 416 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 417 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 418 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 421 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 422 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 423 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 424 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 426 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 427 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 428 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 429 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 431 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 451 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 501 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 502 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 503 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 504 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 505 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 506 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 507 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 508 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 510 /ErrorHandler/index.php
ErrorDocument 511 /ErrorHandler/index.php
```

(I tried with full URL too)

NOTE: /ErrorHandler is a folder. /ErrorHandler/index.php shows an error message.

**[[ EDITED ]]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/notfound.html
```

Use the links instead of a folder name, should work fine then.

EDIT;

It needs to be the absolute path, for example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /405.php
ErrorDocument 406 /406.php
```

Comment: See edit in answer @RafDev. It needs to be the absolute file path.

Comment: if /index.php is your absolute path, then it would be `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` but you should name it so something more name related. I.e notfound.php

Comment: The file is `example.org/ErrorHandler/index.php`

Comment: So try `ErrorDocument 404 /ErrorHandler/index.php`. I would advise commenting out everything except for 404, then you will be able to test it a lot easier. But you could just as easily do `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/ErrorHandler/index.php` which is the method I prefer to use.

Comment: Works when it's just 404. I guess I'll try adding them gradually to figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: Best thing to do @RafDev, glad I could help.

Comment: Just a small update: Status codes 428 (Precondition Required), 429 (Too Many Requests), 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large), 451 (Unavailable For Legal Reasons) and 511 (Network Authentication Required) were the ones causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the filename in the path, as the documentation say:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html
```

Also make sure the right for the file and folder are the good one.

Comment: Doesn't work. Updated question with new code @Destrif

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem and I wish I'd found this post sooner. The problem was the dickens to trace, because I'm on a shared host and traffic is answered at random by any one of 4 clusters, 3 of which run Apache 2.4 and 1 of which runs Apache 2.2. It turns out that ErrorDocument directives with the four error codes 428, 429, 431 and 451 break Apache 2.2 but are ok on Apache 2.4. This doesn't seem to be addressed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Apache prohibit redirecting some http codes.
For example, the [wiki](https://nightlies.apache.org/httpd/trunk/doxygen/group__HTTP__Status.html) clearly states that they manage HTTP error code 418 but redirecting it through ErrorDocument makes the server crash.
So far, I figured out that:
400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 421, 422, 423, 424, 428, 429, 431, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510 and 511
Are all working together and:
418, 419, 425, 426, 427, 444, 449, 450, 451, 456, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499 and 509
Are not working at all.

Notes: I'm using Apache 2.4 and found those lists with a quite experimental method meaning SOME "not working" might actually be working under certain condition.